# problem when trying to navigate a list using the keyboard

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I'm trying to navigate a list using the keyboard. using [ListKeyManager](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#basic-usage) and [FocusKeyManager](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#focuskeymanager) strategy as described in this [post](https://indepth.dev/posts/1147/doing-a11y-easily-with-angular-cdk-keyboard-navigable-lists)

To this end, I have the following components.

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-my-list-item",
  host: { tabindex: "0", role: "list-item" },
  template: ` {{ fruit }} `,
  styles: [
    `
      :host {
        display: block;
        margin: 1rem 0;
        padding: 1rem;
        background-color: #0090ff;
        transition: all 0.3s;
        outline: none;
        color: white;
      }

      :host(:focus) {
        background-color: #28bf5f;
        transform: translateX(1rem);
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class MyListItemComponent implements FocusableOption {
  @Input() fruit = "";

  disabled!: boolean;

  constructor(private readonly elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  focus(origin?: FocusOrigin | undefined) {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
  }

  getLabel?() {
    return this.fruit;
  }
}
```

Parent component

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-articles",
  templateUrl: "./articles.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./articles.component.scss"],
})
export class ArticlesComponent implements AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChildren(MyListItemComponent) items!: QueryList<MyListItemComponent>;

  @HostListener("document:keydown", ["$event"]) onKeyDown(
    $event: KeyboardEvent,
  ) {
    if (this.keyManager) {
      this.keyManager.onKeydown($event);
      console.log(this.keyManager.activeItem); // null
      this.keyManager.activeItem?.focus();
      $event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  fruits = [
    "Apples",
    "Bananas",
    "Cherries",
    "Dewberries",
    "Blueberries",
    "Avocados",
  ];

  private keyManager!: FocusKeyManager<MyListItemComponent>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.keyManager = new FocusKeyManager(this.items).withWrap();
  }
}
```

Parent component template

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
    <app-my-list-item
        *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
        [fruit]="fruit"
        tabindex=0
    ></app-my-list-item>
</div>
```

As I mentioned in the code of the parent component class, I notice that  `this.keyManager.activeItem` has the value null and the `focus` method is not called in the item list component

The detail is that the list elements react only when the element is clicked. but when using the keyboard there is no reaction. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that you're using `@ContentChildren` to query `MyListItemComponent` instances.
But `MyListItemComponent` is directly added in the template of the parent component (`ArticlesComponent`), so we should use `@ViewChildren` instead:

```js
@ViewChildren(ListItemComponent)
  private items!: QueryList<ListItemComponent>;
```

`@ContentChildren` queries will return directives existing inside the `<ng-content></ng-content>` element of your view, whereas `@ViewChildren` queries look at elements that are on your view template directly.

The following Stackblitz contains a working List Key Manager based on the code you posted:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zsbuiy

---

However, when playing around with the Stackblitz, I've noticed the following issue:

- If a user manually focuses an item (via `click`), the `keyManager.activeItem` is not updated and the keyboard interaction will become out-of-sync.

So I've added the following code in `ListItemComponent` and `ArticlesComponent`.
Basically, `ListItemComponent` emits the Subject `focused` every time it gets focused and `ArticlesComponent` subscribes to this stream and updates the `keyManager.activeItem` accordingly.

**`ListItemComponent`:**

```js
export class ListItemComponent implements FocusableOption, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  // ...

  /** Stream that emits when the item is focused. */
  public readonly focused = new Subject<ListItemComponent>();

constructor(
    private readonly _elementRef: ElementRef,
    private readonly _focusMonitor: FocusMonitor
  ) {}

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Start monitoring the element so it gets the appropriate focused classes.
    this._focusMonitor.monitor(this._elementRef, false).subscribe((origin) => {
      if (origin) {
        this.focused.next(this);
      }
    });
  }

  public focus(origin?: FocusOrigin, options?: FocusOptions): void {
    this._elementRef.nativeElement.focus(options);
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._focusMonitor.stopMonitoring(this._elementRef);
    this.focused.complete();
  }
```

**`ArticlesComponent`:**

```js
export class ArticlesComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChildren(ListItemComponent)
  private items!: QueryList<ListItemComponent>;

  private keyManager!: FocusKeyManager<ListItemComponent>;

  // ...

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.keyManager.setFocusOrigin('keyboard');
    this.keyManager.onKeydown(event);
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.keyManager = new FocusKeyManager(this.items).withWrap();

    // If a user manually (programatically) focuses an item, we need to reflect that focus change back to the key manager.
    this.items.changes
      .pipe(
        startWith(this.items),
        switchMap((items) =>
          merge<ListItemComponent[]>(
            ...items.map((item: ListItemComponent) => item.focused)
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe((focusedItem) => {
        this.keyManager.updateActiveItem(focusedItem);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.keyManager.destroy();
  }
```

**Working Stackblitz**:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kcmvt3

The implementation is inspired from **Angular Material Menu Component**:
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/17.0.x/src/material/menu/menu.ts